# Regular Expression in Visual Studio Find & Replace - multiple spaces between search terms

Tags: sql-server, regex, visual-studio, replace, spaces

I require a regular expression for the Visual Studio **Search and Replace** functionality, as follows:

Search for the following term: **sectorkey in (**

There could be multiple spaces between each of the above 3 search terms, or even multiple line breaks/carriage returns.

The search term is looking for SQL statements that have hard-coded SectorKey values inside a SQL **in** statement. These need to be replaced with a SQL join statement - this will be done manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The little arrow to the right of the Find What box is your friend and can help you with the vagaries of the MS regex syntax.

Newline is represented by `\n`, so you can just do `sectorkey( |\n)+in( |\n)+\(` (You need to escape the open paren in your search expression, since that's used in grouping.)

Answer (score 3):

I believe `:Wh+` is what you want.  The Visual Studio regex flavor is very strange; you'll tend to get better results if you consult the [official reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28VS.80%29.aspx).  Expertise with "mainstream" regexes tends to be more of a handicap than a help when it comes to VS.

Comment: Ha hah too true about the handicap.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\s+` to search for one or more adjacent whitespace characters (including tab, CR, LF etc), so your regex would presumably end up looking something like `sectorkey\s+in\s+\(`.

**Edit...**

As Joe points out in his comment, it seems that Visual Studio doesn't support `\s` in Find/Replace expressions, in which case you'll probably need to use something like `[\n:b]` instead. The regex would then become `sectorkey[\n:b]+in[\n:b]+\(`.

Comment: I don't think Visual Studio supports \s. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs(VS.80).aspx